# How do I use the same keyframes when checking / unchecking?

Tags: html, css

I wrote such a code to operate opacity at check time. This worked.

```css
#check1:checked+.box {
  animation: blink 1s;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0%,
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check1">
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    <p>content</p>
    <button type="button">
      <label for="check1">click me</label>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also wanted to do the same operation when unchecking, so I added the animation property.

However, this will not work and the animation at check will not work. Why does this happen?

```css
#check1 + .box {
  animation: blink 1s;
}

#check1:checked + .box {
  animation: blink 1s;
}


@keyframes blink {
  0%, 99% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check1">
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    <p>content</p>
    <button type="button">
      <label for="check1">click me</label>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, I defined an animation with the exact same processing as another name, and it worked normally. Why does this happen? Is there a smart CSS solution?

```css
#check1+.box {
  animation: blink1 1s;
}

#check1:checked+.box {
  animation: blink2 1s;
}

@keyframes blink1 {
  0%,
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes blink2 {
  0%,
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check1">
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    <p>content</p>
    <button type="button">
      <label for="check1">click me</label>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: blink1 and blink2 are identical you need to change blink 2 to do the opposite of blink1

Comment: @zer00ne the trick is that both need to be the same, because the OP need to trigger the same animation on each check/uncheck. Something you cannot do with only one animation

Answer (score 1):

> *"...but why does it stop working when changing it to the checked pseudo-class?"*

The unchecked state needs to have an explicit selector like:

> ```
> #check1:not(:checked)
> ```

but that won't work with current layout because:

- The trigger (i.e. `<label>`) is nested within the target (i.e. `.box`). That looks very awkward. In the updated demo, I had to remove the trigger from the flow by using:

  > ```
  >  position:absolute; z-index: 1; pointer-events:auto
  > ```

  and then the target (i.e. `.box`) `pointer-events: none`
- The checkbox "state" is persistent so if selectors are similar, more than likely the latest version overrides previous selectors. In order to make everything animate from one keyframe I needed behavior that did not persist and had only one state -- `:active`.

---

## [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)

The animation occurs when the checkbox is checked/unchecked. If you take a step back check/uncheck looks a lot like click and the animation itself behaves briefly (like its namesake "blink").  The state of `:active` occurs when the user clicks -- specifically `mousedown` until `mouseup`.

#### HTML

**Required**

> ```
> <br id='target'>
> ...
> <a href='#target' class='link'>X</a>
> ```

#### CSS

**Required**

> ```
> .box { pointer-events: none; }
> .link { ...position: relative; z-index: 1;...pointer-events: auto; } 
> :target + .box :not(:active) { ... }
> ```

---

### Demo 1

```css
.box {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.X {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 5ch;
  height: 2.5ex;
  line-height: 2.5ex;
  border: 2px outset grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1px 3px;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

:target+.box :not(:active) {
  animation: blink 2s linear 0.1s;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 0s;
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<br id='target'>
<article class="box">
  <section class="content">
    <p>Content inside .box</p>
    <a href='#target' class='X'>X</a>
  </section>
</article>
<p>Content outside of .box</p>
```

---

Comment: If the focus is out of focus during animation, it will not work properly. Therefore, I selected a `checked` pseudo-class that does not depend on focus.
Certainly, the answer sentence `focus` pseudo-class is effective, but why does it stop working when changing it to the `checked` pseudo-class?

Answer (score 0):

go through it, I hope it will work for you

```css
   #check1+.box {
      opacity:1;transition: 1s;
    }
    #check1:checked+.box {
      opacity:0;transition: 1s;
    }
```

```html
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">
        <p>content</p>
        <button type="button">
          <label for="check1">click me</label>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It can not animate flashing every click. I am writing an animation that blinks with each click.